# Нужна ли запятая в цитате?

Tags: пунктуация

**"Мы ценим настоящее только когда выбираемся из наших грез."**

Не понимаю, почему она здесь отсутствует? Ведь "только когда выбираемся из наших грез" очень похоже на придаточное времени.

Comment: См также: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=293012

Answer (score 3):

Мы ценим настоящее, **только когда** выбираемся из наших грез.

По правилам запятая ставится.

[Розенталь. § 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы как раз, **только**, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то перед ними ставится запятая (**вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается**): Я эту работу выполню, только если буду свободен (ср.: …если только буду свободен).

Вероятно, именно отсутствие паузы послужило причиной того, что автор не поставил запятую.